# Dockerfile executes python script not as expected

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, couchbase

For a university assignment I need to migrate a postgres dump to couchbase. The whole process has to run within docker services. At the end the whole migration should be executed by running docker compose.

So far the postgres and couchbase initialisation work correctly.

After the initialisation of the databases I would like to do the actual migration by a python script. The service that should run the script always exits with code 0 but nothing happens. That's why I'm pretty sure that it's not executed correctly.

Working directory:

[image: Working directory]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

# Set the working directory in the container to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run script when the container launches
CMD ["python", "./migration_script.py"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"

networks:
    backend:
        external: true

services:
  postgres_db:
    container_name: postgresdb
    image: postgres:13

    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "1234"
      POSTGRES_DB: "dvdrental"

    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - "backend"

  postgres_seed:
    container_name: postgresseed
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: "trust"
        PGPASSWORD: "1234"
    volumes:
        - ./postgres/dvdrental.tar:/tmp/dvdrental.tar:ro
    entrypoint: [ "bash", "-c", "sleep 10 && pg_restore -h postgresdb -U postgres -d dvdrental /tmp/dvdrental.tar" ]
    restart: "no"
    networks:
      - "backend"
    depends_on:
      - "postgres_db"

  adminer:
    container_name: adminer
    image: adminer
    networks:
      - "backend"
    ports:
      - "${UI_PORT?}:8080"

  couchbase_server:
    container_name: couchbase
    image: couchbase:7.1.3
    ports:
      - "8091-8094:8091-8094"
      - "11210:11210"
    networks:
      - backend

  couchbase_init:
    container_name: couchbase_init
    image: couchbase:7.1.3
    volumes:
      - ./init-couchbase.sh:/opt/init-couchbase.sh
    depends_on:
      - couchbase_server
    networks:
      - backend
    command: /bin/sh -c "chmod +x /opt/init-couchbase.sh && /opt/init-couchbase.sh"

  data_migration_service:
    container_name: data_migration
    image: alpine
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - couchbase_init
    networks:
      - backend
```

To check whether the script is executed or not I changed the actual migration script to the following which just checks whether couchbase is running:

migration_script.py:

```
import time
import requests

COUCHBASE_HOST = "couchbase"  # or the appropriate host
COUCHBASE_PORT = "8091"
COUCHBASE_URL = f"http://{COUCHBASE_HOST}:{COUCHBASE_PORT}/pools"

print("Waiting for Couchbase Server to start...")

while True:
    try:
        response = requests.get(COUCHBASE_URL)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            print("Couchbase Server is up and running.")
            break
    except requests.ConnectionError:
        print("Couchbase Server is not available yet, waiting...")
    time.sleep(1)
```

requirements.txt:

```
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
couchbase==4.1.8
requests==2.31.0
```

I already tried to read the logs of the data_migration container. They seem to be empty. That's why I'm pretty sure that the script has never been really executed.

Here are the logs created by running `docker compose up`:

```
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                  docker:desktop-linux
[+] Running 6/6
 ✔ Container couchbase       Created                                                                     0.0s 
 ✔ Container postgresdb      Created                                                                     0.0s 
 ✔ Container adminer         Created                                                                     0.0s 
 ✔ Container couchbase_init  Created                                                                     0.0s 
 ✔ Container postgresseed    Created                                                                     0.0s 
 ✔ Container data_migration  Created                                                                     0.0s 
Attaching to adminer, couchbase, couchbase_init, data_migration, postgresdb, postgresseed
couchbase       | Starting Couchbase Server -- Web UI available at http://<ip>:8091
couchbase       | and logs available in /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs
adminer         | [Thu Nov 30 09:09:08 2023] PHP 7.4.33 Development Server (http://[::]:8080) started
postgresdb      | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
postgresdb      | This user must also own the server process.
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
postgresdb      | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
postgresdb      | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | Data page checksums are disabled.
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
postgresdb      | creating subdirectories ... ok
postgresdb      | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
postgresdb      | selecting default max_connections ... 100
postgresdb      | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
postgresdb      | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
postgresdb      | creating configuration files ... ok
couchbase_init  | Waiting for Couchbase Server to start...
couchbase_init  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase_init  |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
couchbase_init  | curl: (7) Failed to connect to couchbase port 8091 after 1 ms: Connection refused
postgresdb      | running bootstrap script ... ok
data_migration exited with code 0
postgresdb      | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
postgresdb      | syncing data to disk ... ok
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
postgresdb      | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
postgresdb      | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | Success. You can now start the database server using:
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | waiting for server to start....2023-11-30 09:09:09.088 UTC [48] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.12 (Debian 13.12-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.088 UTC [48] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.091 UTC [49] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-30 09:09:08 UTC
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.093 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
postgresdb      |  done
postgresdb      | server started
postgresdb      | CREATE DATABASE
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | waiting for server to shut down...2023-11-30 09:09:09.273 UTC [48] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
postgresdb      | .2023-11-30 09:09:09.273 UTC [48] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.275 UTC [48] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 55) exited with exit code 1
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.275 UTC [50] LOG:  shutting down
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.281 UTC [48] LOG:  database system is shut down
postgresdb      |  done
postgresdb      | server stopped
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgresdb      | 
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.393 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.12 (Debian 13.12-1.pgdg120+1) on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.393 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.393 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.394 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.396 UTC [63] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2023-11-30 09:09:09 UTC
postgresdb      | 2023-11-30 09:09:09.399 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
couchbase_init  |   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
couchbase_init  |                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   551  100   551    0     0   103k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  107k
couchbase_init  | {"isAdminCreds":true,"isROAdminCreds":false,"isEnterprise":true,"allowedServices":["kv","n1ql","index","fts","cbas","eventing","backup"],"isDeveloperPreview":false,"packageVariant":"linux/docker","pools":[],"settings":[],"uuid":[],"implementationVersion":"7.1.3-3479-enterprise","componentsVersion":{"asn1":"5.0.18","os_mon":"2.7.1","lhttpc":"1.3.0","chronicle":"0.0.1","ns_server":"7.1.3-3479-enterprise","kernel":"8.3.2.1","public_key":"1.12.0.1","sasl":"4.1.2","crypto":"5.0.6.3","inets":"7.5.3.1","ssl":"10.7.3.3","stdlib":"3.17.2","ale":"0.0.0"}}SUCCESS: Cluster initialized
couchbase_init  | SUCCESS: Bucket created
couchbase_init exited with code 0
postgresseed exited with code 0
```

I know that the script is executed before the couchbase initialisation is finished but this should not prevent the script from executing and creating some output.

Comment: Try making the exit code of the script dependend on the state. That should let you see whether it really isn't getting executed. Everything looks fine I think, maybe it's just the logging that doesn't work as you expect.

Comment: There could also be an exception that isn't ConnectionError

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to omit the "image" specification from your data_migration_service, just to be sure it is really building the docker image and not just starting an alpine (it should work without omitting it, just to exclude one failure option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omit the image from the data_migration_service.

From the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#definitions):

> Only a subset of Compose file services can be defined under a build
> subsection, others may make use of the image attribute. When a build
> subsection is present for a service, Compose ignores the image
> attribute for the corresponding service, as Compose can build an image
> from source.

[But](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#consistency-with-image)

> Consistency with image When a service definition includes both the
> image attribute and a build section, Compose can't guarantee a pulled
> image is strictly equivalent to building the same image from source.
> Without any explicit user directives, Compose with build support first
> tries to pull the image, then builds from source if the image is not
> found on registry. Compose may offer options to customize this
> behaviour by user request.

This being in conflict, I think what is happening is you are actually executing an [alpine](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) container, which just opens a shell. I am actually not sure why it stops then, but that would be my theory.

Comment: I think you might be correct here!
I managed to keep the migration service running by adding the "tty: true" option in the docker-compose file. There is still zero activity within the container what proofs that the script is not being executed.

Comment: If you have both `image:` and `build:`, it builds the image and assigns it the given name.  So locally the `alpine:latest` image is actually whatever's being built in that Dockerfile, and it will be the base for other images built `FROM alpine`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Should be easy to test. If removing `image:` helps, then it didn't actually build before.